# Make a custom control in Visual Studo 2015 RC

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, blend

In VS 2013 and earlier versions which includes WPF, I can create a custom control (such as rectangular button with custom behaviours) with " Make Into Control" option. But in VS 2015 Community RC, I could not find this option. Did Microsoft remove or rename this feature ? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Connect send an e-mail to me after I send a feedback about this bug:

> **Thank you for reporting this issue with Visual Studio. It has been fixed. "Make Into Control" will be available in Blend in the RTM release of Visual Studio 2015.**

I hope they really solve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I noticed it too.... I think it still available in blend but seem like they removed it from VS.... just create it from blend they seem to have intergrated the 2 environments better in the new version.... I have this version for 3 weeks now and already encountered a number of problems... it seem to be a buggy release especially when u try to use databases.... so some things I still do on vs2013.... I guess we should wait for a service pack or something to have a fully stabled release :)

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's buggy release. I encountered some problems same to you. I searched this option in Blend, however it seems as removed. Do you know any feedback option for Visual Studio and Blend ? We must alert Microsoft :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Microsoft already knows about this... they are the ones removing it in first place :) but it's weird I still have that option in blend 2015 just not in VS.... the issue that bothers me the most is it seem the new version cannot use the wpf extended toolkit thing and that I can't multitask right :)... my VS\blend windows seem to disappear when I click alt+tab... this is like windows vista in the VS world :)

Comment: It is " Make Into User Control". I'm looking for "Make Into Control" option. With " Make Into User Control", you can not create a custom tool(for example custom button). It only creates a special control(for example custom window)....

Comment: if u refer to this window http://prntscr.com/7b15sb it still exists.... just they changed it a bit.... now everytime u choose that make into user control options u have to go to "resources" and choose that template...

Comment: oh I finally understoof your confusion sorry.... yes you are right it seem as custom controls have disappeared from VS2015 but they haven't they just renamed them... basically the difference between user controls and custom controls is that user controls are added as the application resource and custom controls are classed added to your build.... it still exists they just renamed it... when u add a "user control" to ur project it is now actually what u used to call custom controls in the past....

Comment: Due to reputation limits, I cannot put any image.